# Specifying external error pages for JSF applications

Tags: java, jsf, external, custom-error-pages

I'm currently maintaining a legacy ICEFaces 1.8.2 web application and I was wondering if I could define external URL's inside its `web.xml` file for whenever the application generates an error.

The main reason of course is not to show a customer the default Tomcat 6 error page. Also, I can't include the content inside my application's `.war` files because another department in my company is managing the content of those pages.

In particular, I'm interested in showing custom pages for errors 404, 500 and 503.

I tried doing this modification on the application's `web.xml` file:

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>http://myproduction-site.com/error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>http://myproduction-site.com/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html</location>
</error-page>
```

However, I think its illegal to specify those values inside the `web.xml` file.

If it helps, there are a couple Apache servers in front of my Tomcat 6 servers doing load balancing with sticky sessions. Would it be possible to instruct the Apache servers to redirect to these pages whenever an error occurs inside the Tomcat servers?

Is there any other alternative I may not be considering?

I thank you for your time and help!

Comment: A cheap way could be to create local views and put iframe inside each. In faces-config.xml you need to declare view id, can't put URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible by `web.xml`.

The error page location must refer exactly the resource path which will produce the desired result when being passed as argument to [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29). That method does not accept external URLs. It accepts only webapp's own resources.

Your best bet is to create error pages locally which in turn import the external error pages. One of the ways would be using the HTML `<iframe>`, something like as this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTTP Internal Server Error</title>
        <style>
            html, body, iframe {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            html, body {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://myproduction-site.com/error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another way would be using a legacy JSP page with JSTL's [`<c:import>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) which literally embeds the entire HTML response of the target URL in the current response without the need for an iframe (yes, really JSP; the `<c:import>` isn't supported in [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/)).

```html
<%@taglib prefic="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:import url="http://myproduction-site.com/error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html" />
```

Note that if this error page in turn contains *relative* URL references to CSS/JS/image files and forms such as `<script src="some.js">`, then they would all fail. If they can't be fixed to be absolute URLs, then the iframe is really your only resort, provided that the error page itself doesn't contain some JavaScript which breaks out of frames (most modern websites have that in order to prevent phishing attacks).

Comment: Unfortunatly height: 100% has some problems in some browser, but the main idea is good!

Comment: @Alex: I don't forsee any problems with this particular snippet. Perhaps you've experienced problems yourself due to wrong doctype (IE quirks mode) or due to not declaring 100% height on all parent elements (html and body).

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to go with Iframes then. Thanks! :)